# Pandas df.compare() returns the name of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of simlar size. Lets say `df1` and `df2`. For  both the data frames a common column is selected as index. Let's say the name column which is set as index is `Id`.

When I run the code `df1.equals(df2)`, it returns `False`. But when I try to compare both of the data frames using `df1.compare(df2)` only the indexed column name i.e, `Id` is returned **without any values in it**.
What should I conclude from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataFrame.equals](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html) compare not only values, but also index and columns names between both DataFrames.

There is a method for testing equality with more detail:

```
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal
assert_frame_equal(df1,df2)
```

[DataFrame.compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html),shows the differences between two DataFrames. It compares two data frames, row-wise and column-wise, and presents the differences side by side.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a follow up question, if the data frames are not equal, will it result in an assertion error for eg ```AssertionError: DataFrame.columns are different``` ?

Comment: Yes it will give you AssertionError: and then will tell you which column differs. you can find out more about it [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use assert_frame_equal(df1, df2, **check_names**=False)